# How can I reconfigure a Linux guest in Proxmox to use a virtio-based HDD instead of IDE?

Tags: linux, kvm-virtualization, proxmox

I'm running Proxmox 3.3.1 to host a virtual machine running Linux (64bit, kernel version 3.2.0). The virtual machine uses a 512GB HDD which was unfortunately configured to use the `ide` driver when creating the VM.

How can I reconfigure the virtual machine such that the hard disk is accessed using the `virtio` driver?

I found [this forum entry](https://forum.proxmox.com/threads/kvm-change-hdd-from-ide-to-virtio.3933/) on the topic, but the proposed solutions seem to be about doing this for a Windows guest, which requires adding a small dummy HDD in order to driver installation of drivers inside a guest. I suppose this is not needed for Linux.

[Another answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/134989/21925) on this topic (though purely about KVM, not about Proxmox in particular) mentions that

> [..] you'd need to change the drive's label inside of the guest's `/etc/fstab` file, replacing all `/dev/sdX` with `/dev/vdX` [..]

However, I noticed that the Proxmox guest doesn't use `/dev/hdX` at all but rather `/dev/mapper/<vmname>-root` instead. So I'm not sure that answer is really applicable, since Proxmox appears to have it's own way of doing things.

Comment: Just change it to virtio and go on with your life.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Well, how to change it to virtio such that I can go on with my life is precisely what this question is about. :-)

Comment: Doesn't Proxmox provide a nice drop-down box or something like that?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I'd love to hear more about that, because I didn't find any. It does permit changing the driver of the NIC via the web GUI.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I said I didn't find it for what I talk about in my question: Hard Disk Drives. I *did* find it for NICs.

Answer (score 0):

Proxmox basically is the interface for use some hypervisor, then probably you use KVM as hypervisor.

Try to change the disc driver and test, in theory you should have no problem, but maybe grub fail in this case update the grub config, for example:

rm /boot/grub/device.map
grub-mkdevicemap
update-grub2

On some new linux versions grub don't have map file, only do update-grub2 or something.

For do this easily, you can use system rescue cd, and work over you guest vm in a chroot environment. You see mapper path because you're using LVM partitions on you guest.

(I post as answer because I can't comment)